# Leaks and releasing YouTubeThumbnailLoaders

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I have an activity fragment with a single `YouTubeThumbnailView` in it. The view is set from an async task:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  private YouTubeThumbnailView mThumbnailView;

  public class FetchThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask<> implements YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

    protected void onPostExecute(String videoId) {
        mThumbnailView.setTag(videoId);
        mThumbnailView.initialize(YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
        loader.setVideo((String) view.getTag());
    }
  }
}
```

This causes the following error when I launch (or sometimes only when hitting the back button from) a `YouTubeStandalonePlayer` for the video in the thumbnail (when the thumbnail is clicked):

```
E/ActivityThread: Activity com.example.app.MyActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@1cc07092 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.example.app.MyActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@1cc07092 that was originally bound here
```

I assumed this had to do with the warning found in the docs about releasing `YouTubeThumbnailLoader`s when done with them. As suggested in other StackOverflow questions, I tried saving the loader as `mThumbnailLoader` in `MyFragment` from `onInitializationSuccess` and releasing it in the click action:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
    loader.setVideo((String) view.getTag());
    mThumbnailLoader = loader;
}
```

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mThumbnailLoader != null) {
        mThumbnailLoader.release();
    }

    Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(getActivity(), YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY, (String) v.getTag());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

How do I correctly release the loader to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by the activity (and therefore fragment) being destroyed by something other than the click event. Simply repeating the `mThumbnailLoader.release();` block in `onDestory()` fixed the issue.

Additionally, the actual crash was being caused by another issue. On its own the leaked `ServiceConnection` error is only visible in the log without any user-facing impact on the app.